# Connected normal space can just be a single point?

Tags: general-topology

Using Urysohn's Lemma, it can be shown that a connected normal space $X$ (with more than one point) is uncountable. But then how can it be that a connected normal space might just be a single point? Is this immediate from Urysohn's Lemma?

Comment: Trivially?${}{}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Come again?

Comment: There is no way of decomposing a singleton into two non-empty disjoint sets... everything much hold vacuously.

Comment: Urysohn makes no (nonvacuous) statement about one-point spaces. But the very definition of normal is trivially verified for one-point space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it’s immediate from the definitions of connectedness and normality. A one-point space is clearly not the union of two disjoint non-empty sets, open or otherwise, so it’s connected. A one-point space doesn’t contain two disjoint closed sets, so the defining condition of normality is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: OK, now I got it.

Comment: @Sachin: Good. (By the way, what I wrote is basically just a longer version of what Asaf meant when he asked ‘Trivially?’.)